# Magento 2.3.3 showing Pending Payment status after successful order complete

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal, order-status

I have configured Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution in magento 2.3.3 for paypal and card payment methods.

When placing an order using paypal, once the order is successful, order status changing to processing.

But when placing an order using card payments, once the order is successful, status is not changing to processing still it shows Pending Payment.

Any help on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by using the below link,

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18148

```
For now, we have changed line 38 of vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment/State/RegisterCaptureNotificationCommand.php from:
$state = $order->getState() ?: Order::STATE_PROCESSING; to $state = Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as the Pending Payment status after successful order complete status.
I tried the file modification procedure:

or now, we have changed line 38 of vendor / magento / module-sales / Model / Order / Payment / State / RegisterCaptureNotificationCommand.php from:
$ state = $ order-> getState ()?: Order :: STATE_PROCESSING; to $ state = Order :: STATE_PROCESSING;

Actually now the orders do not remain in "Pending Payment" but unfortunately instead of going to the "PROCESSING" status they go directly to the "COMPLETE" status.

Did I do something wrong?